# Avoid dragging unintentionally in Raphael

Tags: javascript, raphael

In this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pgschr/zd7p1Lkq/14/) I have a Raphael canvas with a rect that can be clicked or dragged.

If you move the mouse to the rect and then click it, you may slightly move it (the text will show you that). I need in my application to handle the click and ignore the drag movement when the user intended to click. For example, I need to enable the drag only if it's greater than, say, 5 px. Is there a way to make Raphael not move the rect if the intention is just to click?

```
var paper = Raphael("canvas", 600, 600); 
var title = this.paper.text(50, 10, 'click on the square');
var rect = this.paper.rect(20, 20, 30, 30);
rect.attr('fill', 'black')

var start = function () {
      this.odx = 0;
      this.ody = 0;
},
move = function (dx, dy) {
      title.attr('text', 'mouse moved')
      this.translate(dx - this.odx, dy - this.ody);
      this.odx = dx;
      this.ody = dy;
},
up = function () {};

rect.drag(move, start, up);

rect.mousedown(function(e){
      title.attr('text', 'mouse down')      
})
```

Comment: Have you tried using click rather than mousedown ?

Comment: The click event is fired after the mousedown and mouseup events, so the problem doesn't go away, the rect would be dragged unintentionally before the mouseup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store *initial coordinates* when the movement has started and ignore while the distance between *current coordinates* and *initial coordinates* is less than `x` pixels.

```
var paper = Raphael("canvas", 600, 600); 
var title = this.paper.text(50, 10, 'click on the square');
var rect = this.paper.rect(20, 20, 30, 30);
var PX_TO_IGNORE = 5; // pixels to ignore

rect.attr('fill', 'black')

var start = function () {
      this.odx = 0;
      this.ody = 0;
      this.initialCor = null;
},
move = function (dx, dy) {
  // check if not initialized(if it`s first click)
  if(this.initialCor == null) {
    this.initialCor = {x: dx, y: dy};
    return;
  }

  // ignore PX_TO_IGNORE pixels(basically circle with radius PX_TO_IGNORE)
  if(distance(this.initialCor.x, dx, this.initialCor.y, dy) < PX_TO_IGNORE ) {
    return;
  }

  title.attr('text', 'mouse moved')

  this.translate(dx - this.odx, dy - this.ody);
  this.odx = dx;
  this.ody = dy; 
},
up = function () {
  title.attr('text', 'mouse up')
};

rect.drag(move, start, up);

rect.mousedown(function(e){
  title.attr('text', 'mouse down')      
})

// helper function to calcuate distance between two coordinates
function distance(x1,x2,y1,y2) {
    return Math.sqrt( Math.pow((x1-x2), 2) + Math.pow((y1-y2), 2) );
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/htLn819y/4/

Comment: Can you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59271991/find-the-correct-shift-of-a-second-rect-in-raphael)

Comment: @ps0604 Sorry, the link is broken